# Os X. Не могу поставить модуль tidy на php

Tags: php, apache, macos, xampp

Xampp. Скрипт выдает Fatal error: Call to undefined function tidy_parse_string().

гуглил, но ничего не работает.

в php.ini добавил "extension=tidy.so"

установил homebrew

установил brew install tidy-html5

brew link tidy-html5

brew link --overwrite tidy-html5

brew install homebrew/php/php56-tidy

для проверки поставил в php скрипт

```
$command = "tidy -version";
exec($command, $return, $code);
if (count($return) > 0) {
    echo "Tidy available!";
}

if (extension_loaded("tidy")) {
echo "PHP Tidy loaded!";
}
```

скрипт выводит только Tidy available
и по-прежнему Fatal error: Call to undefined function tidy_parse_string().

что можно сделать чтобы решить проблему?

**upd.**

php_error_log:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/tidy.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/tidy.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

по пути, указанному в php.ini файла нет. вопрос, откуда взять tidy.so?
поиск его не нашел. значит я неправильно что-то инсталлировал, если даже файла нигде нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С этим расширением действительно заморочки на os x.

Ставим zend studio trial - в составе пакета есть нужная нам последняя версия файла расширения tidy.so

Файл перетаскиваем в нужный путь (путь extension_dir в php.ini - я прописывал ссылку на свою созданную папку), перезагружаем сервер. в phpinfo появится отдельный блок по tidy.

zend studio:
http://www.zend.com/de/products/studio/downloads#Mac%20OS

[image: находите в finder app в программах и правый клик мыши чтобы влезть в пакет]

[image: ищите поиском в пакете tidy.so]

Comment: спасибо, помогло! но загадка осталась - при инсталляции пакета почему нигде нет tidy.so